# column =char(1), and also =char(0)

Tags: character-encoding, mysql-5.7

I have a table that includes a column `foo`.

`show create table` shows `` `foo` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0' ``, so the column should contain [binary strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-value-literals.html): the 0 and 1 bytes.

```
select ascii(foo),
ord(foo),
foo=char(1),
foo=char(0),
char(1)=char(0)
from table_name
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

yields

```
ascii(foo)   ord(foo)   foo=char(1)   foo=char(0)   char(1)=char(0)
         0          0             1             1                 0
         1          1             0             0                 0
```

I'd expect it to yield

```
ascii(foo)   ord(foo)   foo=char(1)   foo=char(0)   char(1)=char(0)
         0          0             0             1                 0
         1          1             1             0                 0
```

Can someone please explain what's going on?

---

<sub>Nor is this restricted to the `select` clause. It happens in the `where` clause also: `select distinct ascii(foo) from table_name where foo=char(0)` and `select distinct ascii(foo) from table_name where foo=char(1)` both return only 0.</sub>

---

```
select @@version
5.7.21-20-57-log
```